# why i'm not getting more than one arbitrary arguments in the following code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

In this code i'm writing a function that gives information about cars:

```
car_info('subaru', 'outback', color='blue', tow_package=True)
```

My function:

```
def car_info(manufacturer,model,**specification):
    info = {}
    info['manufacturer'] = manufacturer
    info['name'] = model
  
    for key,values in specification.items():
        info[key] = values
        return info
```

Answer (score 1):

Your return statement is in the for scope, so it is returned in the first iteration.
For solving it make it function scoped:

```py
def car_info(manufacturer,model, **specification):
    info = {}
    info['manufacturer'] = manufacturer
    info['name'] = model
  
    for key,values in specification.items():
        info[key] = values
    return info
```

You can also just update your info dictionary:

```py
def car_info(manufacturer,model, **specification):
    info = {**specification}
    info['manufacturer'] = manufacturer
    info['name'] = model
    return info
```